# $.ajaxPrefilter throws Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert null to object Exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, javascript-objects

I want to change the AJAX Header with `$.ajaxPrefilter` and tried following:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    delete options.headers["myOwnHeader1"];
    options.headers["myOwnHeader2"] = "test";
});
```

In the Network Console (Chrome) the `myOwnHeader2` is set and the `myOwnHeader1` not. But it throws the following Exception: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert null to object` on `options.headers["myOwnHeader2"] = "test";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `options` object does not necessarily contain a `headers` property - only if given in the global `$.ajaxSettings` or in the current (original) options. So your choices are

- using `$.ajaxSetup({headers: {}});`, maybe with the `myOwnHeader2` already set
- wrapping your delete/extend operations in a `if ("headers" in options)` block
- creating the headers object dynamically in the prefilter if it does not exists:

```
options.headers = options.headers || {};
delete options.headers["myOwnHeader1"];
options.headers["myOwnHeader2"] = "test";
```